# Linux usb: how to let's the bNumConfigurations value is 0x01?

Tags: android, linux, usb

I'm doing a android mobile phone test in linux PC, sometimes, finding PC couldn't read mobile Number as below:

```
             **XXXXX@XXXXXX:~$ adb devices
             List of devices attached**
```

I running the lsusb commands and get the below result:

```
*Bus 002 Device 088: ID 0fce:5178 Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB 

Device Descriptor:

  bLength                18

  bDescriptorType         1

  bcdUSB               2.00

  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)

  bDeviceSubClass         0 

  bDeviceProtocol         0 

  bMaxPacketSize0        64

  idVendor           0x0fce Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB

  idProduct          0x5178 

  bcdDevice            2.28

  iManufacturer           2 Sony

  iProduct                3 LT*****

  iSerial                 4 CB5A****

  **bNumConfigurations      0**

Device Qualifier (for other device speed):

  bLength                10

  bDescriptorType         6

  bcdUSB               2.00

  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)

  bDeviceSubClass         0 

  bDeviceProtocol         0 

  bMaxPacketSize0        64

  bNumConfigurations      1

Device Status:     0x0000

  (Bus Powered)*


Based on this, if reconnet my mobile phone into linux PC, this is OK,and running lsusb commands, it will get the below:

*Bus 002 Device 089: ID 0fce:5178 Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB

Device Descriptor:

  bLength                18

  bDescriptorType         1

  bcdUSB               2.00

  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)

  bDeviceSubClass         0 

  bDeviceProtocol         0 

  bMaxPacketSize0        64

  idVendor           0x0fce Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB

  idProduct          0x5178 

  bcdDevice            2.28

  iManufacturer           2 Sony

  iProduct                3 LT*****

  iSerial                 4 CB5A****

  **bNumConfigurations      1**
```

Configuration Descriptor:

```
bLength                 9

bDescriptorType         2

wTotalLength           62

bNumInterfaces          2

bConfigurationValue     1

iConfiguration          0 

bmAttributes         0xc0

  Self Powered

MaxPower              500mA

Interface Descriptor:

  bLength                 9

  bDescriptorType         4

  bInterfaceNumber        0

  bAlternateSetting       0

  bNumEndpoints           3

  bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class

  bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass

  bInterfaceProtocol      0 

  iInterface              5 MTP

  Endpoint Descriptor:

    bLength                 7

    bDescriptorType         5

    bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN

    bmAttributes            2

      Transfer Type            Bulk

      Synch Type               None

      Usage Type               Data

    wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes

    bInterval               0

  Endpoint Descriptor:

    bLength                 7

    bDescriptorType         5

    bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT

    bmAttributes            2

      Transfer Type            Bulk

      Synch Type               None

      Usage Type               Data

    wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes

    bInterval               0

  Endpoint Descriptor:

    bLength                 7

    bDescriptorType         5

    bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN

    bmAttributes            3

      Transfer Type            Interrupt

      Synch Type               None

      Usage Type               Data

    wMaxPacketSize     0x001c  1x 28 bytes

    bInterval               6

Interface Descriptor:

  bLength                 9

  bDescriptorType         4

  bInterfaceNumber        1

  bAlternateSetting       0

  bNumEndpoints           2

  bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class

  bInterfaceSubClass     66 

  bInterfaceProtocol      1 

  iInterface              0 

  Endpoint Descriptor:

    bLength                 7

    bDescriptorType         5

    bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN

    bmAttributes            2

      Transfer Type            Bulk

      Synch Type               None

      Usage Type               Data

    wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes

    bInterval               0

  Endpoint Descriptor:

    bLength                 7

    bDescriptorType         5

    bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT

    bmAttributes            2

      Transfer Type            Bulk

      Synch Type               None

      Usage Type               Data

    wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes

    bInterval               0
```

Device Qualifier (for other device speed):

```
 bLength                10

  bDescriptorType         6

  bcdUSB               2.00

  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)

  bDeviceSubClass         0 

  bDeviceProtocol         0 

  bMaxPacketSize0        64

  bNumConfigurations      1

Device Status:     0x0000
```

(Bus Powered)*

it's clear that the bNumConfigurations value is 1 will get the correct result. 
if there is a possible that, I didn't to reconnect the android mobile phone and linux PC, only input one or more linux shell commands, let's the PC could renew to get the android mobile number?

Comment: Please format your question properly. It's best to denote code or output by putting four spaces in front of each line

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question right, you'd like to be able to run `adb get-serialno` consistently. I've found this command to fail for three reasons:

1. The ADB daemon on the device gets in a bad state.
2. USB on the host or device fails.
3. The ADB server on the host PC gets in a bad state.

I've worked a lot with Samsung phones on Ubuntu and ordered these from problems I've seen most frequently to less frequently. For cases 1 and 2, I normally find a detach and reattach to fix it or sometimes repeated command invocations. Again, if I interpret your question properly, you'd like to be able to do everything from the command line. On Ubuntu, you unbind and rebind the device which should approximate a detach and reattach cycle. From command line, that should look something like this:

```
# $1 - VID[:PID]
usb_id_to_bind()
{
  declare -r dev_name="$(lsusb|sed -rn 's_^Bus ([0-9]{3}) Device ([0-9]{3}): ID '"$1"'.*_/dev/bus/usb/\1/\2_p')"
  declare -r dev_path="$(udevadm info -q path -n"$dev_name")"

  basename "$dev_path"
}

usb_unbind()
{
  echo "$(usb_id_to_bind "$@")"|sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
}

usb_bind()
{
  echo "$(usb_id_to_bind "$@")"|sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind
}

usb_unbind 04e8:6866; usb_bind 04e8:6866
```

If that doesn't work, you might have to reboot your phone (`adb reboot`).

For 3, you can fix this with with a `adb kill-server` followed by the command again.

Answer (score 0):

Using the below commands to unbind the driver

*# $1 - VID[:PID]

usb_id_to_bind()

{

declare -r dev_name="$(lsusb|sed -rn 's_^Bus ([0-9]{3}) Device ([0-9]{3}): ID 
'"$1"'.*_/dev/bus/usb/\1/\2_p')"

declare -r dev_path="$(udevadm info -q path -n"$dev_name")"

basename "$dev_path"
}

usb_unbind()

{

echo "$(usb_id_to_bind "$@")"|sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind

}

usb_bind()

{

echo "$(usb_id_to_bind "$@")"|sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind

}

usb_unbind 04e8:6866;

but while to run the lsusb commands, it seemed the mobile phone still attached as below:

*Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 007 Device 002: ID 03f0:0325 Hewlett-Packard

Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

**Bus 002 Device 014: ID 0fce:5178 Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB**

Bus 002 Device 006: ID 046d:c03d Logitech, Inc. M-BT96a Pilot Optical Mouse

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub*

How to let's the android device renew to connect the linux PC? I running below commands:
sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-5/authorized" and let's the android mobile renew to connect PC, it's failed.